# How to find all x and y value of 2D matrix equal to z in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a very big 2D matrix , I want to find all x and y position which is equal to number z. I used find function but it seems it doesn’t return correct values.

```
[x y] = find(matrix,z);
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `help find`? (Hint: Replace 1 character by two others and you should be there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the point of the second argument in `find`. Try

```
[x y] = find(matrix == z);
```

`find` operates on `logical` arguments. If you do not pass in a `logical`, it just finds all non-zero elements. The second argument sets a cap on how many occurrences of non-zeros will be found, not the thing to search for.